# Akeneo PIM - add media to product validation

Tags: rest, attributes, akeneo, pim

we are trying to add media to a product from a REST call, and facing an error.

```
{
    "code": 422,
    "message": "Validation failed.",
    "errors": [
        {
            "property": "attribute",
            "message": "Cannot set the property \"banner_image\" to this entity as it is not in the attribute set"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
API ENDPOINT: {{url}}/api/rest/v1/media-files
form-data:
product -> {"identifier":"1273192971", "attribute":"banner_image", "scope": null,"locale":null, "data":null}
file -> testfile.jpg
```

If anyone can help, how to properly enter the attribute in JSON?

Regards,
Bassam

we are facing error:

Answer (score 0):

as you can see you need your attribute banner_image to be added to your family before you try submit the request.

Go to Settings -> Families -> Select all from checkbox and hit bulk actions.
Select set attributes requirements then click on add attribute to add your banner_image attribute and save.

After that your request should work.